# Как при выводе ответа сделать нужное кол-во пробелов, а не столько, сколько ставится автоматически?

Tags: python

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

код, он работает, но с выводом (именно с кол-вом пробелов есть проблема):

```
def squared(start, end, div):
    s = ' '
    for k in range(start, end + 1):
        if (k * k % div != 0): 
            s += (str(k * k) + ' ' * 5)[0:5]
        s += ' ' if (k + 1) % 10 != start % 10 else '\n'
    print(s)
```

**Ввод**

```
squared(11, 99, 10)
```

**Ожидаемый результат**

```
121  144  169  196  225  256  289  324  361
441  484  529  576  625  676  729  784  841
961  1024 1089 1156 1225 1296 1369 1444 1521
1681 1764 1849 1936 2025 2116 2209 2304 2401
2601 2704 2809 2916 3025 3136 3249 3364 3481
3721 3844 3969 4096 4225 4356 4489 4624 4761
5041 5184 5329 5476 5625 5776 5929 6084 6241
6561 6724 6889 7056 7225 7396 7569 7744 7921
8281 8464 8649 8836 9025 9216 9409 9604 9801
```

**Вывод**

```
121   144   169   196   225   256   289   324   361   
441   484   529   576   625   676   729   784   841   
961   1024  1089  1156  1225  1296  1369  1444  1521  
1681  1764  1849  1936  2025  2116  2209  2304  2401  
2601  2704  2809  2916  3025  3136  3249  3364  3481  
3721  3844  3969  4096  4225  4356  4489  4624  4761  
5041  5184  5329  5476  5625  5776  5929  6084  6241  
6561  6724  6889  7056  7225  7396  7569  7744  7921  
8281  8464  8649  8836  9025  9216  9409  9604  9801
```

**Сообщение**

**Line 1 differs: out:**

```
>121   144   169   196   225   256   289   324   361<
```

**corr:**

```
>121  144  169  196  225  256  289  324  361<
```

**UPDATE:**

**Ввод**

```
squared(4, 33, 9)
```

**Ожидаемый результат**

```
16   25   49   64   100  121  169
196  256  289  361  400  484  529
625  676  784  841  961  1024
```

**Вывод**

```
16   25    49   64    100  121   169 
196   256  289   361  400   484  529 
 625  676   784  841   961  1024
```

**Сообщение**

**Line 1 differs: out:**

```
>16   25    49   64    100  121   169<
```

**corr:**

```
>16   25   49   64   100  121  169<
```

**UPDATE 2.0:**

переделал код и теперь проходит только первые 6 тестов, а на 7 опять с пробелами что-то не так

```
def squared(start, end, div):
    s = ''
    for k in range(start, end + 1):
        if (k ** 2 % div != 0): 
            s += str(k ** 2) + ' ' * (1 + len(str(end ** 2)) - len(str(k ** 2)))
        if (k + 1) % 10 == start % 10:
            s += '\n'
    print(s)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#format-examples

Answer (score 5, accepted):

У вас ведь прямо в задании написано, каким образом напечатать 4 позиции, дополненные пробелами, используя f-строки. А в вашем способе печатается 5 позиций:

```
(str(k * k) + ' ' * 5)[0:5]
```

Это как минимум 5 пробелов за счёт `' ' * 5`, и из них вырезается 5 символов срезом `[0:5]` (с 0-го по 4-й, т.е. 0,1,2,3,4 - 5 символов).

Используйте способ печати (формирования строки), указанный у вас в задании, т.е. в вашем коде будет так:

```
s += f'{k*k:<4}'
```

Что касается обновлённого вопроса. Скорее всего вам нужно не формировать строку вывода сразу, а накапливать результат в списке и потом уже выводить из списка накопленные числа, форматируя их определённым образом. Это вообще более правильный подход и в данном случае он должен помочь.

Comment: @Андр Я дополнил ответ

Comment: первый тест прошел(по пробелам) теперь второй не проходит хотя мы же теперь правильно используем вывод через f-строки(сейчас прикрпелю в вопрос что неправильно)

Comment: @Андр Вам нужно всё-таки быть внимательнее и больше стараться. Учебные задания даются для того, чтобы вы усваивали материал. Если всё будут решать за вас, а вы не будете стараться, то материал просто не усвоится, вы зря потратите время.

Comment: я переделал что прошло первые 6 тестов, а 7 опять пробелы((

Comment: решил данную проблему